# Forming a GQL query with != not equals

Tags: google-app-engine, filter, google-cloud-datastore, gql, gqlquery

I am trying to form a GQL query that:

```
SELECT * FROM IvlsRun where origInstrument = 'Catalyst_Dx' and practiceId != '100004'
```

Finds all IvlsRun(s) where the origInstrument = 'Catalyst_Dx'... but I don't want any of them with practiceId = 10004.

Everytime I add the practiceId != 100004 or practiceId != '100004' I get an error.

I am new to GQL.  I am doing this through the datastore viewer.

The error is pretty basic, telling me I don't know how to use GQL:

Learn more about GQL syntax.
no matching index found.

Comment: Could you please post the error you are getting?

Comment: The error is pretty basic, telling me I don't know how to use GQL:

Learn more about GQL syntax. no matching index found.

Comment: To get around this I am simply specifying alternate practiceId(s) instead of trying to NOT EQUALS the one I don't want.  This is working for now.

Answer (score 2):

You must define custom index when you use query with one or more inequality filters on a property and one or more equality filters on other properties. See [Index Configuration](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/indexes#Index_Configuration).